# How to prove the extension of Morera's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I prove that,

if $f(z$) is continuous in a region G (probably multiply connected), and if for every $\zeta$ in G, there exists a disk D that contains $\zeta$ such that:

$\begin{equation}
\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz=0
\end{equation}$

for all closed curves $\gamma$ piecewise smooth , closed in D. Then $f(z)$ is analytic in G.

Comment: $f$ is analytic on each $D$, and since $G$ is covered by such $D$s, $f$ is analytic on $G$.